# Patent infringement issues, damages and royalty settlement

Tags: infringement, royalty, retrospective

Person A has a patent in India, granted in 2000. A applies for protection in the US in 2005 and gets granted in 2010. Firm B and C were using the patent from 2004 and 2006 respectively to manufacture and sell a product in the US.

1. From which year will A be reimbursed given that she has been granted the patent in 2010 in the US?
2. What will happen if B stops production in 2009?
3. What will happen in B stops production in 2011?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B will invalidate A's patent with the indian patent as prior art because a priority claim can be made only for 12 months so the US application can't claim priority to the indian application and therefore has 2005 as the filing date.

B could also invalidate A's patent by proving that they had the product in public use prior to the filing date of the patent.

B could claim a ["prior use" exception](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/ip/global/prior_user_rights.pdf) and not pay royalties (pre AIA that's pretty much theoretical).

---

Other than that, a valid patent can claim royalties for the time between publishing of the application and grant under some circumstances. See for example [here](https://sunsteinlaw.com/media/judithBPLA.pdf):

> This provisional right comes with two 
>   caveat [...]
>
> The invention as claimed in the 
>   patent must be “substantially identical” to 
>   the patent as claimed in the published patent 
>   application. 35 U.S.C. § 154(d)(2) [...]
>
> The second caveat concerns notice. The 
>   statute requires the infringer to have 
>   “actual notice” of the published 
>   application. 35 U.S.C. § 154(d)(1)(B).  [...]
>
> Commentators agree that based on 
>   congressional intent, the courts will 
>   likely require notice from the applicant. 
>   See, e.g., 82 
>   JPTOS at 748; Patrick J. 
>   Birde, Nicholas J. Nowak, 
>   Analyzing 
>   Provisional Rights for Patent Applicants, 9 
>   No. 12 Intell. Prop. Strategist 1 (2003); 
>   Terence P. Ross, 
>   Intelectual Property 
>   Law: Damages and 
>   Remedies § 
>   3.08 
>   (2004); Brian J. Massey, 
>   Reasonable 
>   Royalties for 18 Month Patent Publication 
>   Infringement: 
>   An Unreasonable Remedy for 
>   Smal Businesses, 
>   8 J. Small & Emerging 
>   Bus. L. 87, 103 (2004).

-> If B infringed only while the patent was still an application (but not before filing), A won't be able to enforce royalties or punishment as high/strong as if B infringed afterwards, but will be able to enforce royalties nonetheless.

Therefore, if B stops production before the grant, they will still "be punished" (with royalties) but that should be less than if they infringed a granted patent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate clarification. Just one more question, why will the royalties/punishment be less for a pending patent than a granted patent?

Comment: @SatyakiChakravarty fairness, the infringer couldn't have been sure the patent would be granted/granted in that form.

Comment: can you please send me a reference to the fairness argument? It will be helpful since I am writing a paper and references are always good for papers.

Comment: @SatyakiChakravarty I don't have one, but I suppose the congressional reasoning for the word "reasonable" in 35 U.S.C. § 154(d) would be the right place to go as it would constitute the original source.

Comment: @SatyakiChakravarty alternatively: https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=provisional+rights+patent+application+reasonable&hl=de&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit0vTl9JDaAhXMh6YKHRT8AV0QgQMIJDAA